# Call a java applet method via javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, applet

How can I call a function when a specific event occurs in my java Applet ?

In my Javascript I has the following code, that always return a empty value.

```
$(function () {
    alert(document.applets[0].returnClientId());
});
```

I need to call this alert, just when a specific method is executed. To be more specific, the method called identify, that exists in my java Applet.

The identify method, exists in my Util.class, that don't extends from JApplet.
My FormMain.class extends from JApplet and I call some methods (including the identify method) from this Util.class.

**UPDATE**: My Java Code

```
public String getClientid() {
    return clientid;
}

public void setClientid(String clientid) {
    this.clientid = clientid;
}

public String returnClientId() {
    return getClientid();
}

public void identify() {
    try {
        fingerprintSDK.prepareForIdentification(this.template);

        ResultSet rs = identifyStmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {         
            byte[] templateBuffer = rs.getBytes("template");

            Template referenceTemplate = new Template(templateBuffer);

            boolean matched = fingerprintSDK.identify(referenceTemplate);

            if (matched) {
            // ui is my FormMain instance
                ui.showImage(GrFingerJava.getBiometricImage(template,
                        fingerprint, fingerprintSDK));

                ui.writeLog("Found. Client = "
                        + rs.getString("Name"));

                ui.setClienteid(rs.getString("Cliente_Id"));

                ui.disableTemplate();                   
                return;
            }
        }

        ui.writeLog("Not Found.");
        ui.enableTemplate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        ui.writeLog(e.getMessage());
    } catch (GrFingerJavaException e) {
        ui.writeLog(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The Identify method is executed just when my User put the finger in the biometric device.

Someone has some idea ?

Comment: [These are the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html). We can't reproduce your code, though. Is `returnClientId()` declared `public`? Does it run without errors?

Comment: @Raffaele All method are public

Comment: Check on the Java side if the String is actually empty (BTW, why is there `getClientid()` and `returnClientId()`???)

Comment: @Raffaele I know, I can just return clientid.  My String is actually empty, I fill this String just when my Identify method is executed.

Comment: What a bad question! Please, review it! If I understand the flow correctly, when the applet is loaded the client id is blank. It's set to some non-blank when `Util.identify()` is called (but you don't tell how this happens). The problem I see here is that the Javascript alert executes on DOM loaded (this is what jquery does when you write `$(function() {})`), when the string **can** be null. And in fact it is

Comment: But how can I do to, execute a function just when Identify method is executed ? The Identify is executed just when the user put the finger in the biometric device.

Comment: Since `identify()` is called on the Java side, you can certainly insert a line in that method to show a Java dialog like [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JOptionPane.html). [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: @Raffaele to be clear, How can I execute a javascript function, but just when identify method is executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following JS function

```
function foo(client) {
    alert(client);
}
```

you'll modify your `Utils.java` as follows

```
public void identify() {
    // the rest of your code
    String id = rs.getString("Cliente_Id");
    ui.setClienteid(id);
    // call the Javascript function
    JSObject.getWindow(ui).eval(String.format("foo(%s)", id));
}
```

- [Invoking Javascript code from an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html)
- [Java to Javascript communication (Official Oracle docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html)

To compile the code using `netscape.javascript.*` package you need the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/plugin.jar`. [See here](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#JAVA_TO_JS)

> In order to call JavaScript, Java code uses the
>   netscape.javascript.JSObject and netscape.javascript.JSException
>   classes. Since the release of Java 2, Standard Edition version 1.4,
>   these classes are provided in the jar file jre/lib/plugin.jar within
>   either the Java Development Kit or Java Runtime Environment. If you
>   reference these JavaScript classes, you will need to add plugin.jar to
>   your compilation classpath. This can be done through your Java IDE, if
>   you use one, or by passing the -classpath command-line argument to the
>   Java compiler javac.
>
> At run-time, the Java Plug-In automatically makes these classes
>   available to applets, so no changes to the applet or how it is set up
>   are necessary.